# Question about Mann Whitney U and Rank Sum test in Scipy

Tags: python, biostatistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, scipy

I am trying to compare the average visual acuity between to sets of independent groups using logMAR visual acuity.

As the sample size is small I have opted for the Mann-Whitney U test which, in my understanding, is the same as the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test.

I am using `scipy` in `python` and my code is as follows;

```
import scipy.stats as stats

mPVR = [0.00, -0.18, -0.08, 0.30, 0.48, 0.60]
iERM = [1.00, 0.60, 0.78, 0.10, 0.00, 0.18, 0.60, 0.48, -0.18, -0.08]

MWU = stats.mannwhitneyu(mPVR, iERM, use_continuity=True, alternative="two-sided")

WRS = stats.ranksums(mPVR, iERM, alternative="two-sided")

print(MWU)
print(" ")
print(WRS)
____________________________________________________________________________________________

MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=22.0, pvalue=0.4131761509873124)
 
RanksumsResult(statistic=-0.8677218312746247, pvalue=0.385546631571102)
```

Now I am asking these questions for my learning.

**1) Why are the p-values produced by the Mann-Whitney U and Rank Sums test different if the two tests are the same?**

**2) If they are indeed not the same (which I very much suspect given that there are two different functions) then which test would be most appropriate to use in this scenario?**

**3) If the tests should produce the same p-value, then what have I done wrong with the above?**

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the software implementations, but you might explore the effect of setting `use_continuity` to false.

Comment: @SalMangiafico I.e. is one algorithm correcting for ties, while the other is not?

Comment: Hi, @Alexis .  Yes, it appears that the difference between the functions is `scipy.stats.ranksums` doesn't correct for ties or allow for continuity correction, as the response by @utobi indicates.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation page of `scipy.stats.ranksums` reads

> This test should be used to compare two samples from continuous
> distributions. It does not handle ties between measurements in x and
> y. For tie-handling and an optional continuity correction see
> scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.

Indeed, by setting `use_continuity=True` and removing one instance of 0.60 from `iERM`, you will see that the two tests give identical results.

It goes without saying that in this case, you should definitely use Mann-Whitney.